# using ajax get result to great expandable table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

Im trying to create expandable table row by adding json items I get from ajax between existing tabel rows.

my problem is I dont know how to iterate over this json and how to add values to rows and finaly those rows between existing rows.

My table:

```
<table class="allComps" style="text-align: center;">
              <tr>
                <th class="">Nimi</th>
                <th class="">Looja</th>
                <th class="">Tähtaeg</th>
                <th class="">Osalejate arv</th>

              </tr>
            <?php
             $n=0;
            foreach(allComps() as $row) {
                echo '<tr id="allCompsRow'.$n.'" onclick="fun(this.id)">
                        <td class="">' . $row['compname'] . '</td>
                        <td class="">' . $row['firstname'] .  " " . $row['lastname'] . '</td>
                        <td class="">' . $row['time_created'] . '</td>
                        <td class="">' . $row['numUsers'] . '</td>
                        <td class="" style="display:none;">'.$row['id'].'</td>

                      </tr>';
                echo '<tr ><td colspan="0"><table class="span" id="span"></table></td></tr>';
                $n++;
            }
            ?>
            </table>
```

My jQuery:

```
window.fun=function(clicked_id){
        var row=document.getElementById(clicked_id);
        var id=row.getElementsByTagName("td");

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getQuestions.php",
            datatype: "json",
            data:{
                compid:  id[4].innerHTML
            },
            success: function(response){
                for( i=0;i<response.length,i++){
                    if()
                    var newRow='<tr class="span">
                    <td>response</td>'
            }

        });

    }
```

The get result format :

```
[{id":"109","compid":"161","quest_type":"Jalgpall","ans_type":"ansText","cor_ans":"","team1":"","team2":"","textq":"fwefwf"}]
```

Comment: Try looking into the `document.createElement` function. You'll want to create each table row and set the `textContent` or `value` as appropriate for the `td` elements. Since you're using jQuery you can do `$('<tr>')` to get an element if I recall, then use the `.append` call to add more values.

Comment: Just for reference: [DataTables add row](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) and [DataTables ajax](https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)